# Iterate with iterator-range in python

Tags: python, pandas

In this dataframe I want to iterate with a span of 3 rows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, 43), columns=['slow', 'fast', 'p'])
df.slow = 5
df.fast = [
        
    2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,
    5,6,6,4,5,6,
    6,5,4,5,6,6,7,
    7,7,6,5,5,4,5,6,6,7,
    8,8,9,8,7,7,7,7,7,7
      
          ]
df.p = [
    
    1,1,1,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,
    7,6,5,4,4,5,
    6,7,6,6,7,7,8,
    7,6,8,9,10,4,5,3,2,2,
    4,4,5,6,7,8,8,8,8,8
    
]
```

the logic:
If fast > slow and p >= fast and p[-1] p[-2] p[-3] > slow = array append True

my attempt:

```
iterarray = [-1, -2, -3]
array = []

for i in range(len(df.index[2:])):
    if df.fast[i] > df.slow[i] and df.p[i] >= df.fast[i] and df.p[i:i+len(iterarray)] > df.slow[i:i+len(iterarray)]:
        array.append(True)
    else:
        array.append(False)
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How can I achieve the proper iteration?

Comment: What to you mean to iterate over a span of 3? That if the this was also true 1 (or 2, or 3) row before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your last condition `df.p[i:i+len(iterarray)] > df.slow[i:i+len(iterarray)]` you compare a 3 pair of numbers. This 3 pairs have 3 pair result (True or False) and python couldn't merge these 3 results naturally.
You must use `.all()` that if all pairs is `True` return `True`.

```
...
if df.fast[i] > df.slow[i] and df.p[i] >= df.fast[i] and (df.p[i:i+len(iterarray)] > df.slow[i:i+len(iterarray)]).all():
...
```

Comment: interestingly with your solution I get a slightly different result opposed to this: `df.p[i-1] > df.slow[i-1] and df.p[i-2] > df.slow[i-2] and df.p[i-3] > df.slow[i-3]`

Comment: In your post you compred `df.p[i:i+len(iterarray)]` with `df.slow[i:i+len(iterarray)]` that equals to `df.p[i] > df.slow[i] and df.p[i+1] > df.slow[i+1] and df.p[i+2] > df.slow[i+2]` wchi is not that you wrote in the comment (i-1, i-2, i-3).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if the condition (fast greater than slow) is true and also for some records ago, you can do this:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3]:
    df[f"col_-{i}"] = (df['slow'] < df['fast']) & (df['fast'] <= df['p']) &(df['slow'].shift(i) < df['p'].shift(i))
```